# Is it possible to tag or label a single file in Accurev?

Tags: accurev

Need an information from you for Accurev.
Is there a way to tag/label a file in Accurev?

Ex - A developer X promotes 'n' number of files in a stream for a defect 12345. Same developer promotes 'p' number of files in the same stream for defect 67890.
At a point, customer has requested for reviewing and listing all files changed for defect 12345.

Is there a way by which all the required files can be pulled from Accurev by a tag/label?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create a snapshot stream,  this is the equivalent to labeling files.  After you promote defect 12345, create a snapshot stream off of this stream.  Next you promote defect 67890 and make another snapshot.  Now you can populate (pull) the content from both of these streams.

Comment: Whenever I am creating a snapshot, it is pulling all the files in the backed stream. However, I want to pull only the changed files.

Comment: Yes, the snapshot stream contains the entire content of its parent stream.  If you only wanted the specific files of a promotion, you could use the command 'accurev pop -t' and specify the transaction number of the promotion for each defect.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have managed to pull only the changed files by comment.
Accurev hist to list all files by comment (defect no.) and then accurev pop to pull the changed files.